# How to compose multiple classes into a single semantically-named class?

Tags: sass

I've been reading up on Block-Element-Modifier naming conventions, semantically-named style rules, etc. and I'd like to replace multiple class names in my html with a single, semantic class name. Can't seem to make it happen, though. Example:

I'd like to replace my Bootstrap navbar

`<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">`

with

`<nav class="header__navbar" role="navigation">`

I know I could use jQuery to do this procedurally, but I'd prefer not to. I've tried several approaches using variable names, #{} interpolation syntax, mixins, and @extend, etc. but just get syntax errors or invalid results.

Is this just not something Sass was designed to do?

Comment: How about showing what you've actually tried rather than asking "can Sass do this?"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Is this just not something Sass was designed to do?

Sass does support this use case.

What you need is [extending](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend).

1. Have `navbar`, `navbar-default` and `navbar-fixed-top` classes defined as you would with a non-semantic approach:

   ```
    .navbar { display: table; }
    .navbar-default { background-color: deeppink; }
    .navbar-fixed-top { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; }
   ```
2. Below, extend your `header__navbar` class with those:

   ```
   .header__navbar {
     @extend .navbar;
     @extend .navbar-default;
     @extend .navbar-fixed-top;
   }
   ```
3. Once you get rid of non-semantic classes in your HTML markup completely, you no longer need them in your CSS. So turn them into placeholder selectors aka silent selectors. To do so, replace the `.` with `%` both in the rules where they are defined and in `@extend` directives that use them. E. g.:

   ```
    %navbar { display: table; }
    %navbar-default { background-color: deeppink; }
    %navbar-fixed-top { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; }

   .header__navbar {
     @extend %navbar;
     @extend %navbar-default;
     @extend %navbar-fixed-top;
   }
   ```

Comment: Huh. What you proposed in #2 above was the very first thing I tried, Andrey. No kidding! Anyway, no syntax errors, but it resulted in all kinds of chaos. But I tried it again - and it worked! Not sure what happened, but I thank you, mon ami.

Comment: Follow up: while the above example is working, I tried the approach on another set of these classes from Twitter's Bootstrap library. No syntax errors or anything, but the results are different and incorrect. Heights and widths are not the same, for instance. This is what occurred previously with the above example that now works.

Comment: Have a look into the developer console to see what's going on there. PS Are you using the official `bootstrap-sass`?

Comment: I am using the official version, yes. New info: I tried all this on sassmeister.com and it works just fine. This is an ember.js project with ember-cli. I'm thinking the problem lies with one of those components and not with BootStrap or Sass. I'll pursue that angle. And thanks again!

Comment: Cheers for ember-cli! Your problem might be that you're reusing those classnames and all usages get extended. Try %placeholder selectors instead.

Comment: Can't use placeholders; I'm using a 3rd party library and don't want to modify their rules. I solved that last problem though, by replacing default ember-cli CSS preprocessor broccoli-sass which uses libsass with broccoli-ruby-sass. Apparently libsass is faster but new and has bugs which caused my problem. I'm up and running now

Answer (score 8):

### Another way is you can extend multiple class in an single line like:

**Normal way**

```
.header__navbar {
  @extend .navbar;
  @extend .navbar-default;
  @extend .navbar-fixed-top;
}
```

**Extend multiple class in single line**

```
.header__navbar {
  @extend #{'.navbar','.navbar-default','.navbar-fixed-top'};
}
```

This extend example same work for first example.

**Thanks**

Comment: This extending in a single line is great, didnt even know I could do that

Comment: @virtualLast Yes, a lot of things we can't learn yet.